# Brezis' exercise 5.21.6

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to solve exercise 5.21.6 in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*.

> Let $(H, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ be a real Hilbert space and $|\cdot|$ its induced norm. Let $(\mathcal L(H), \| \cdot \|)$ be the Banach space of all bounded linear operator on $H$. Let $T \in \mathcal L(H)$ with $\|T\| \le 1$. Let $f \in H$ and define for each $n \in \mathbb N^*$,
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sigma_n (f) &:= \frac{f+Tf+T^2f+\cdots+T^{n-1}f}{n}, \\
> \mu_n (f) &:= \left ( \frac{I+T}{2} \right )^n f.
> \end{align}
> $$
> Here $I:H \to H$ is the identity map. Our purpose is to show that
> $$
> \lim_n \sigma_n (f) =\lim_n \mu_n (f) = \pi_{N(I-T)} f.
> $$
> Here $\pi_{N(I-T)} f$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto the kernel $N(I-T)$ of $I-T$.
>
> 1. Check that $N(I-T) = R(I-T)^\perp$ with $R(I-T)$ the range of $I-T$.
> 2. Assume that $f \in R(I-T)$. Prove that there is a constant $C$ such that $|\sigma_n (f)| \le C/n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^*$.
> 3. Deduce that for every $f\in H$, one has $\lim_n \sigma_n (f) = \pi_{N(I-T)} f$.
> 4. Let $S = \frac{I+T}{2}$. Prove that $|u-Su|^2 + |Su|^2 \le |u|^2$ for all $u\in H$. Deduce that
>    $$
>    \sum_{i=0}^\infty |S^i u -S^{i+1}u|^2 \le |u|^2
>    \quad \forall u \in H
>    $$
>    and that
>    $$
>    |S^n(u-Su)| \le \frac{|u|}{\sqrt{n+1}} 
>    \quad \forall u \in H, \forall n \in \mathbb N^*.
>    $$
> 5. Assume $f \in R(I-T)$. Prove that there is a constant $C$ such that $|\mu_n (f)| \le C/\sqrt{n}$ for all $n \in \mathbb N^*$.
> 6. Deduce that for every $f\in H$, one has $\lim_n \mu_n (f) = \pi_{N(I-T)} f$.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

4. We have
   $$
   \begin{align}
   |u|^2 &= |u-Su|^2 + 2 \langle u-Su, Su \rangle + |Su|^2 \\
   &= |u-Su|^2 + \langle u - Tu, u+Tu \rangle + |Su|^2 \\
   &= |u-Su|^2 + (|u|^2-|Tu|^2) + |Su|^2 \\
   &\ge |u-Su|^2 + |Su|^2 \quad \text{because} \quad \|T\| \le 1.\\
   \end{align}
   $$
   We apply above inequality iteratively and get
   $$
   \begin{align}
   |u|^2 &\ge |u-Su|^2 + |Su|^2 \\
   &\ge |u-Su|^2 + ( |Su-S^2u|^2 + |S^2u|^2 ) \\
   &\ge |u-Su|^2 + |Su-S^2u|^2 + ( |S^2u-S^3u|^2 + |S^3u|^2 ) \\
   &\ge \sum_{i=0}^n |S^i u -S^{i+1}u|^2 + |S^{n+1} u|^2.
   \end{align}
   $$
   It follows that
   $$
   |u|^2 \ge \lim_n \sum_{i=0}^n |S^i u -S^{i+1}u|^2 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty |S^i u -S^{i+1}u|^2.
   $$
   Notice that $\|S\| \le 1$, so $|S^i(u-Su)| \ge |S^n (u-Su)|$ for all $i \le n$. Then
   $$
   |u|^2 \ge \sum_{i=0}^n |S^n (u-Su)|^2 = n |S^n (u-Su)|^2.
   $$
5. Let $f \in R(I-T)$. Then there is $x \in H$ such that $f=(I-T)x$. Then
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \mu_n (f) &= S^n(I-T)x \\
   &=2S^n(I-S)x.
   \end{align}
   $$
   It follows that $|\mu_n (f)| \le \frac{2|x|}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.
6. Let $f \in N(I-T)$. Then $(I-T)f=0$. Then $S f= \frac{I-T}{2}f+ Tf=f$. Then $S^n f= f$ for all $n$. Then $\mu_n (f) = f = \pi_{N(I-T)} f$. If $f \in R(I-T)$ then $\mu_n (f) \to 0$ by (5.). By (1.), we have $0=\pi_{N(I-T)} f$. Let's prove the claim for $f \in \overline{R(I-T)}$ by density argument. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $f_\varepsilon \in R(I-T)$ such that $|f-f_\varepsilon| < \varepsilon$. We have
   $$
   \begin{align}
   |\mu_n (f) - \mu_n (f_\varepsilon)| &=   | S^n (f-f_\varepsilon)  |\\
   &\le \|S^n\| |f-f_\varepsilon| \\
   &\le \|S\|^n |f-f_\varepsilon| \\
   &\le |f-f_\varepsilon|.
   \end{align}
   $$
   Then
   $$
   \begin{align}
   & |\mu_n (f) - \pi_{N (I-T)} f| \\
   \le & |\mu_n (f)-\mu_n (f_\varepsilon)| + |\mu_n (f_\varepsilon) - \pi_{N(I-T)} f_\varepsilon| + |\pi_{N(I-T)} f_\varepsilon - \pi_{N(I-T)} f| \\
   \le & |\mu_n (f_\varepsilon) - \pi_{N(I-T)} f_\varepsilon| + (1+\|\pi_{N(I-T)}\|) |f-f_\varepsilon|.
   \end{align}
   $$
   It follows that $\limsup_n |\mu_n (f) - \pi_{N (I-T)} f| \le (1+\|\pi_{N(I-T)}\|) \varepsilon$. The claim then holds for $f \in \overline{R(I-T)}$ by taking the limit $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$. In the general case $f \in H$, we write write $f=f_1+f_2$ with $f_1=\pi_{N(I-T)} f$ and $f_2=\pi_{\overline{R(I-T)}} f$.

Comment: In (4), you should have a coefficient of $\frac 12$ on the inner product term after you switch to $u$ and $Tu$ (each side of the inner product has a coefficient of $1/2$, and you can only cancel one of them with the $2$ multiplier). But as you only need this term to be non-negative, it has no effect on the final outcome.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are right! Thank you so much for your checking!

Comment: Strictly as a matter of clarity, in the next step for the $|u|^2$ inequality, I suggest putting parentheses in the final expression to clarify what is in the summation and what is not, and also add an additional line dropping the $S^{n+1}u$ term. Also, (5) should start at the "Notice" line, as you've already finished (4).

Comment: on (5), where did that coefficient come from? The inequality you just showed says that $$|\mu_n(f)|^2 = \frac 4n n\left|S^n(x-Sx)\right|^2 \le \frac 4n|x|^2$$

Comment: @PaulSinclair It follows from (4) where $|S^n(u-Su)| \le \frac{|u|}{\sqrt{n+1}}$.

Comment: I see that I missed there was a second conclusion to be shown in (4), but your inequality (which I mistakenly said should be part of (5)), only shows $|S^n(u-Su)| \le \frac{|u|}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: I see - your final inequality in (4) is mistated, it should $(n+1)|S^n(u-Su)|^2$ as the sum is from $i = 0$ to $i=n, n+1$ indices. I didn't see any problems in (6). So the two minor corrections in (4) appear to be all.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you so much for your correction! I think your elaborate comments deserves to be posted as an answer so that I can accept...

Comment: On (5), some change is needed, but it is a bit tricky as the problem statement (at least as reproduced here) is in error. Apparently you are to show that $\|\mu_n\| \le \frac C{\sqrt n}$, or equivalently that $|\mu_n(f)| \le \frac C{\sqrt n}|f|$. Including $f$ on one side but not the other was a mistake. Note that your inequality is in terms of $|x|$, not $|f|$. So you should fix that, and you might as well change the denominator to $\sqrt n$ instead of $\sqrt {n+1}$ since that is what they asked for. "Solution verification" questions often get answered just in comments like this.

Comment: @PaulSinclair In (5), I think the author means the constant $C$ is dependent of $f$. I think changing from $\sqrt{n}$ to $\sqrt{n+1}$ will confuse readers who read our comments...

Comment: The word "constant" means it *doesn't* change with the variables. Here, $f$ and $n$ are the variables. They meant $C$ to be constant.

Comment: @PaulSinclair $f$ is fixed at the beginning. I think the statement is better stated as "...a constant $C$ depending only on $f$...".